# No need to register base Activity class in the Manifest?

Tags: android, overriding, extends

I have my own base abstract class which extends `Activity` class.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();
}

public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // do extra stuff 
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.layout_for_activity1;
    }
}
```

My base class `BaseActivity` is not registered in the `Manifest` file and I do not get any error.

Is this a time bomb (not registering base class in Manifest) or this is the way it should be? Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the docs, the `<activity>` on the manifest:

> Declares an activity (an Activity subclass) that implements part of
>   the application's visual user interface. All activities must be
>   represented by  elements in the manifest file. **Any that are**
>    **not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be**
>    **run**.

Think about it like this: If there's an activity (any class that extends `Activity` or a class that extends it) that you will navigate to at some point in your application, it needs to be declared in the manifest. Regardless of **how** you reach that activity. This excludes classes that only extend the `Activity` class but you can't reach directly.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Your answer kinda is misleading. You say its a timebomb not to register the BaseActivity in the manifest, yet you go on to say NOT to register it

Answer (score 17):

You *dont* need to register BaseActivity class in manifest because its not the one you call in intent to launch.

for example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
startActivity(i);
```

In above code, you need to have `Activity1` activity registered in manifest because you are mentioning it in intent, **not** the `BaseActivity` class.

Comment: ^ This. Unless you plan on actually running the BaseActivity on its own you only need to register the Activities that are extending it.

Comment: yes, of course... logically *concrete* classes should be registered.

Comment: It was actually me, because I misunderstood the answer at first *sorry*. If you edit your answer (anything so it lets me change the vote) I'll up vote since yours was first and valid too

Comment: i think clicking your down-vote (the one in orange color) would help you to un-vote

Answer (score 0):

No need to register Base class in manifest because it is an abstract class , we cannot make an object of  Abstract class, we can define only its methods and declaration.